# PHP array_filter VS foreach performance

Tags: php

I have an array that is large and has 3 nested depths. I want to filter it but `array_filter` is not a complete solution so I have to use `foreach`.

I've read in some places that even if `array_filter` finds the relevant array, it continues to check, is this true?

My understanding here is that the `foreach` loop is faster.

```
$users = array();
$users[0]['id'] = 7;
$users[0]['username'] = 'coin';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'XXXX';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 1;
$users[1]['id'] = 8;
$users[1]['username'] = 'asdasd';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'AAAA';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 2;
$users[1]['rooms'][1]['socket'] = 'BBBB';
$users[1]['rooms'][1]['room'] = 4;

example_function($users,'AAAA')
```

The result i want to give:

```
['room'] = 2
```

Comment: Based on official documentation

< Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. **If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array**.>

Each value that satisfy the callback functionwill be in the result array.
If you want to filter an array You need to continue searching even after finding the first case.

[PHP: array_filter][1]
  
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @MBAbb But I understand you. I will look for a unique value in the array. Wouldn't it be silly to continue?

Comment: I dont know about array_filter implementation but i found this.   [Are array_* functions faster than loops?](https://www.levijackson.xyz/posts/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/)

Comment: @CoinAnalyzer maybe you are looking for something like [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) rather than filter? If finding the first occurrence only is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Remy I updated the question. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Users can connect to multiple rooms. Socket code I have.

I need to find out which room it is in via the socket code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry. Yes it should be 2, I spelled it wrong.

Comment: @Remy Can you check my answer and help?

Comment: Generally speaking, when working with large arrays in PHP, the slowest part of the code is probably the part _creating_ the array, and I would optimize in that area. Where is the data coming from? A database? If not a database, can you introduce one? How slow is this code anyway? Does it run once per request or in a background task?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, Background task.